# Could not copy the files .... because it was not found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

I got a asp.net mvc project from my friend. This is her project but i need to work on it. So when i try to start it, there are some errors. Here is that errors;

```
Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\x86\sqlceme40.dll" because it was not found.
Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\x86\sqlcecompact40.dll" because it was not found.
Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\x86\sqlceer40EN.dll" because it was not found.
Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\x86\sqlceca40.dll" because it was not found.
Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\x86\sqlcese40.dll" because it was not found.
Could not copy the file "_bin_deployableAssemblies\x86\sqlceqp40.dll" because it was not found.
```

I did some search and found some solutions about updating my nuget packages. I did all updates including EntityFramework.SQLServerCompact. But i have still that errors and have no idea what to do. So can someone could help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that all this references included into project?

Comment: @demo I was, and now i checked my references section for you and there is a yellow warning icon on EntityFramework.SQLServerCompact should i remove and install it again?

Comment: well, you can :) or in case this references are located in some specific folder in solution, You can try to add them manually

Comment: @demo i did uninstall and installed it again, same errors :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after updating VS to 153.

However since I am not Using SqlServerCompact edition anywhere in my project:  I use Entity Framework to SQL Server proper I didn't feel the need to have those references and provider in the web.config.

In the Web Project - I used NUGET to remove all references to SQLServer Compact Edition. Then I Removed the reference to SqlCEProvider in the providers section of the web.config. Recompiled and everything works as expected.

Comment: This is an assumption you should first verify with the OP: one cannot assume they don't need the references. Better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command:

```
Update-package -Reinstall
```

from Console administrator packages (PM)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error using the following steps (order of some steps matters):

- Installed [SQL Server CE 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876). I had to install the x64 version to match my OS, but it included the x86 redistributable files referenced in my project.
- Using NuGet, removed EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact from my project
- Using NuGet, removed Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact from my project
- Using NuGet, installed EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact, which also installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i uninstalled  SQLServer Compact Edition and installed again from nuget packages